# loading a xml file instead of download

Tags: php, mysql, xml, xslt

Hey guys I have stored few xml files in database and want to get them for xslt transformation. But I am unable to load it for transformation, they get downloaded to PC. I want to process it instead of download.

here is my code: I am accessing the file with its id.

```
  // Fetch the file information
    $query = "
        SELECT `pname`,`pdata`
        FROM `plist`
        WHERE `pid` = {$id}";
    $result = $dbLink->query($query);


    if ($result) {
        // Make sure the result is valid
        if ($result->num_rows == 1) {
            // Get the row
            $row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
             echo "$row[0]";
              header("Content-Type:text/xml");

         header("Content-Disposition: inline"); 
            echo $row['pdata'];          
        }
          mysqli_free_result($result);
```

---missing something here to get file data--

until now it gets downloaded but i want to continue the transformation

```
$xml = new DOMDocument;
$xml->load(what goes here??);

$xsl = new DOMDocument;
$xsl->load('file.xslt');

//etc
```

any help appreciated.

Comment: Why are you storing XML in a database? If you are, how are you storing it?

Comment: @ iswinky they are very few of them so it makes easy to handle them. storing in blob.

Comment: Instead of fetching the information from the database and echoing it to screen; return it to your main script and use `loadXML()` instead of `load()`

Comment: And your current code to retrieve the data is flawed, you're echoing the data ___before___ sending the headers.... if you had error logging enabled, this would be issuing warnings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working solution that i found later enjoy..:)

```
<?php           
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
// Get the id
$id = intval($_GET['id']);

// Make sure the name is in fact a valid
  if ($id <= 0) {
  die('The id is invalid!');
  } else {
  // Connect to the database
  include 'config.php';
 }
// Fetch the file information
$query = "select id, name, data from data_table where id ={$id};";
$resultx = $mysqli->query($query) or die($mysqli->error . __LINE__);

$arr = array();

if ($resultx->num_rows > 0) {
 while ($row = $resultx->fetch_assoc()) {
  $arr[] = $row['tdata'];
         }
 }


   $string = implode(",", $arr);

        // Load XML file
     $xml = new DOMDocument; // create new document
     $xml->loadXML($string); // load string to it
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a string with the XML then you can use `$xml->loadXML($row['pdata'])` I think to parse the XML.